# Waterman butterfly projection in Mapnik

Tags: coordinate-system, mapnik

Like the title says, how would someone configure Mapnik to use the [Waterman butterfly projection](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/map_projections.png) ?

Otherwise, what other tools would be able to render using this projection ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think mapnik or proj4 are able to render that kind of projection.

According to that [excellent post](http://indiemaps.com/blog/2011/04/dymaxion-projection-in-openlayers/), [Openlayers](http://openlayers.org/) with [protovis library](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/dymax.js) would be able to render not exactly the Waterman projection but the Fuller projection (also called [Dymaxion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dymaxion_map)).

You even have an online example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130511014947/http://indiemaps.com/projects/openlayers-dymaxion/examples/world_dymaxion.html).

[image: dymaxion - openlayers]

Comment: That projection could be a good alternative indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not for Mapnik, but at least the [Polyhedral Geographic Projections](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/geo/polyhedron) plugin for **d3.js** can render that projection.

[image: Screenshot of the d3.js example]

---

Example from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4458497:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  background: #fcfcfa;
}

.stroke {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.fill {
  fill: #fff;
}

.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

.land {
  fill: #222;
}

.boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.polyhedron.v0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 550;

var projection = d3.geo.polyhedron.waterman()
    .rotate([20, 0])
    .scale(118)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var defs = svg.append("defs");

defs.append("path")
    .datum({type: "Sphere"})
    .attr("id", "sphere")
    .attr("d", path);

defs.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("use")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "stroke")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "fill")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("path")
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr("d", path);

d3.json("/mbostock/raw/4090846/world-50m.json", function(error, world) {
  svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
      .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
      .attr("class", "land")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "boundary")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .attr("d", path);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

</script>
```