# Dymaxion/Butterfly alternative projection for QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I've been reading the Dymaxion and Butterfly projections are not open source, so can not be used with QGIS.

Are there alternatives to these available in QGIS?

I'm looking for a single projection so I can export relatively-accurate SVG shapes of countries around the world when I need them.

It's important these countries are relatively-close to the way they would appear on a globe.

Answer (score 1):

Proj.4 knows the Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area projection `+proj=isea`, but not the inverse projection. For that reason, it is not usable by GDAL.

I guess the Waterman Butterfly projection will fail for the same reason.

[Waterman butterfly projection in Mapnik](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16926/waterman-butterfly-projection-in-mapnik) lists some alternatives.

Comment: I not see changes [at proj.org/ISEA](https://proj.org/operations/projections/isea.html)... **Any 2021 news** here? someone with news?   No ISEA based on [Snyder equal-area projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snyder_equal-area_projection),  for GDAL (therefore PostGIS, QGIS, etc.)?  There is an old  suggestion for fast "Invese Snyder" [at this 2011 article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220916433_Optimization_of_Inverse_Snyder_Polyhedral_Projection).